# Converting images to youtube supported video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a 1.5hr video for uploading to `Youtube` using `ffmpeg` with a 1280x720 screenshot and a audio file.
I've tried
but it takes a long time for `Youtube` to process the video. how can i minimize the processing time.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 2 -i input.png -i audio.ogg -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

Comment: Out of sheer astonishment- you want a 1.5 hour still image? Ah ok I get it- it's the music that matters?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-movflags faststart` to your command line and youtube will start processing it while uploading.

Could also try lowering the framerate to 1 with `-r 1`